# How to save a static class to file in Java?

Tags: java, file, static

Given a static class, for example `MyStaticClass`, which has two methods for saving and loading itself to/from a file, like for example:

```
private static void save() throws IOException {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("myfile.dat"));
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(???);
  oos.close();
}

private static void load() throws IOException {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.dat"));
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
  ??? = (MyStaticClass) ois.readObject();
  ois.close();
}
```

What should I put in place of `???` where I would normally put the instance of the object?

Is there maybe a way to save a static class to file different from the one used for instances?

Comment: You don't save classes, you save instances. So make `save()` take an instance of the class as an argument, and `load()` return the loaded instance.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - You don't save classes or instances, you save bits.  They can represent anything.

Comment: @HotLicks I mean with an `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: there is furthermore a ClassNotFoundException in the second method. You have to catch that or expand the throw-clouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as Im aware you cant do it like that. But you could write the static fields individually rather than the whole class in one go.

eg.

```
public class MyClass() {

    private static String staticField1;
    private static String staticField2;

    static {
        load();
    }

    private static void saveField(String fieldName, Object fieldValue) throws IOException {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("MyClass-" + fieldName + ".dat"));
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
      oos.writeObject(fieldValue);
      oos.close();
    }


    private static Object readField(String fieldName) throws IOException {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("MyClass-" + fieldName + ".dat"));
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
      Object value = ois.readObject();
      ois.close();

      return value;
    }

    private static void save() throws IOException {
      saveField("staticField1", staticField1);
      saveField("staticField2", staticField2);
    }

    private static void load() throws IOException {
      staticField1 = (String)readField("staticField1");
      staticField2 = (String)readField("staticField2");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "static class". If you mean that the *state* of the class is composed of static data members only, then store these data members in the save() method, and update them in the load method.

If, on the other hand, you have non-static state you want to save, then it looks like the save method shouldn't be static, and the load method should be static, and return a new instance.